# Piping continious stream to grep as search term for search in a file

Tags: command-line, grep, fifo

I have a named fifo and I am writing random number to this fifo.
When I write to fifo I want to find written text in `numbers.txt` file and write the result row to stdout.

Content of `numbers.txt` file is:

```
1 one
2 two
3 three
... and so on
```

I want to search text which piped to `grep` in this file.
For example If I write `1` to named pipe, grep should print `1 one` to stdout.

I am running command shown as below in first terminal:

`cat <> myfifo | grep -f - numbers.txt`

And  I am writing to fifo in another terminal show as below:

`echo 1 > myfifo`

But I can't see any output in stdout in first terminal window.

I want to see `2 two` in first terminal output when I execute `echo 2 > myfifo` in second terminal window. How to achive this?

Comment: use the command

tail -f [your filename along with path here without brackets]

this could be helpful to you... this immediately reflects the changes to the screen as soon as the contents of file changes...

Comment: `grep -f myfifo numbers.txt`, as in my answer.

Comment: @tomas I tried this but not worked. I am writing text to pipe but `grep -f myfifo numbers.txt` command not printing any output to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat <> myfifo` opens the named pipe for both reading and writing. As long as the pipe is open for writing, the reader doesn't reach the end of the file. So `cat` never reaches the end of its input, so it never closes its output which is the pipe to `grep`, so `grep` never reaches the end of the input for the `-f` option.

Grep can't start searching until it knows what pattern to search. So it remains blocked forever without even starting to read from `numbers.txt`.

If you want to search for the patterns coming through `myfifo` then just use

```
grep -f myfifo numbers.txt
```

You can also write it `cat <myfifo | grep -f - numbers.txt` but that's needlessly complicated.

Note that a pattern like `1` matches any line containing `1`, such as `11 eleven`. If you want to match only lines that begin with one of the numbers coming through the pipe, use something like

```
<myfifo sed 's/^0*/^0*/; s/$/ /' | grep -f - numbers.txt
```

Comment: This worked fine. 
But fifo is closing after write to it. Is this expected behavior? I solved this with grepping fifo in a infinite while loop. 

But this is not working if I write to pipe with continious stream. 
For example: I have a shell script `printnumbers.sh` that looping infinite and printing 1,2,3,... to stdout each second.

I am running `./printnumbers.sh > myfifo` in one terminal, and in another terminal:
while true; 
do
    grep -f myfifo numbers.txt | awk '{print $2; system("")}'
done
This printing to stdout when I stop print to fifo.

Comment: @mesuutt When the last writer on a pipe closes the pipe, readers get an end-of-file indication. I don't understand the rest of your comment. What are you trying to achieve? As I explain in my answer, grep reads the patterns before it starts processing the text to search. Do you want to search the data again each time a new pattern comes on the pipe? If so you will need to call grep (or awk) in a loop, since it has to read the data again and again each time.

Comment: Yes I want to search the data again each time a new pattern comes to pipe. Also I read from pipe within a loop. I have a bash script file `printnumbers.sh` that print numbers each second in infinite loop. Your solution works if I write to pipe as `echo 1 > myfifo` and print `one` to stdout but if I write to pipe  numbers as: `./printnumbers.sh > myfifo` not printing anything to stdout due to stop the `./printnumbers.sh > myfifo`. https://gist.github.com/mesuutt/92e1d6286c442b2003fe2c67d2133d7b

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code doesn't work, I guess it has to do with the `<>` redirection with the receiving `cat` and it not responding to the End-Of-Text sign, so that nothing get through to `grep`. Again, I *guess*. Someone more knowledgeable might explain this.

Anyhow, the following will do.

Writing terminal:

```
$ printf "%s\n" {1..7} > myfifo
```

Or:

```
$ cat > myfifo
1
2
3
4
```

Receiving terminal:

```
$ grep -f myfifo numbers.txt 
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five
6 six
7 seven
```

Or this:

```
cat myfifo | grep -f - numbers.txt
```

Comment: I tried this but not worked. I am writing text to pipe but command not printing any output to stdout. Also I want to get `1 one` as output when I write `1` to named pipe not all of the content of numbers.txt

Comment: @mesuutt It should be fine. Make sure you're indeed writing the the same pipe as you read from, so namely that both terminals are in the same directory. Use `pwd` if needed.

Comment: `cat myfifo` works as expected but `cat myfifo | grep -f - numbers.txt` or `grep -f myfifo numbers.txt ` not printing anything to stdout. I have grep 2.25 version.

Comment: @mesuutt Same as me. Which version of Bash do you have?

Comment: I tested on bash 4.3.46 and zsh 5.2 on Arch linux.

Comment: @mesuutt Just like me (Bash only). I don't know then. It works fine here. Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64.